# Installed lubuntu, worked great, however upon reboot menu items are now gone

Tags: lubuntu, menu, lxde

So, I installed lubuntu, and was working great. However, when I logged out of it, everything that was in the menu was gone, and now it only contains "run" and "logout".

Also, sometime after trying to locate the menu file, I tried to logout, and got a notice saying "Too many open files", and was unable to logout.  Maybe these two incidents are related?

I'm wondering how I would go about restoring the menu back to its initial state. I'm also pretty much a complete n00b to linux, but did grow up on DOS so am not averse to command prompts.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There isn't even a bug report for this... Lubuntu 14.04 seems to be pretty bad...

Answer (score 0):

remove/rename the ~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/desktop.conf file and then reboot.  That should re-create the file.